# mule download all files from s3 bucket

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

```
<flow name="listobjects">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="listobjects" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <s3:list-objects config-ref="Amazon_S3" bucketName="demo"  doc:name="Amazon S3" maxKeys="5" />

   <!--  <payload-type-filter expectedType="java.util.List" doc:name="Payload"/> -->
    <foreach collection="#[payload]" doc:name="For Each">
   <!-- <foreach doc:name="For Each file"> -->
     <logger message=" inside foreach...... #[payload.getKey()]  ...." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <s3:get-object-content config-ref="Amazon_S3" bucketName="demo" key="#[payload.getKey()]"  doc:name="Amazon S3"/>
        <object-to-byte-array-transformer/>
      <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\output" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="#[payload.getKey()] "></file:outbound-endpoint> 
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

I have bucket name called demo.
In that bucket I have 3 pdf files. I want to download all files and put it in c:\output folder.

I hit my url like http://localhost:8081/listobjects.

But I got the error:

> Could not find a transformer to transform "CollectionDataType{type=org.mule.module.s3.simpleapi.SimpleAmazonS3AmazonDevKitImpl$S3ObjectSummaryIterable, itemType=com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler, mimeType='*/*'}". (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException). Message payload is of type: SimpleAmazonS3AmazonDevKitImpl$S3ObjectSummaryIterable

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because after the `foreach` processor the payload is an instance of an S3 class, and you haven't specified any Content-Type to return. So Mule tries to transform the S3 instance to the default SimpleDataType and fails.
One way to solve it is simply to add something like

```
<set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Content-Type" />
<set-payload value="{'result': 'ok'}"/>
```

at the end to make it explicit.

Also note that in your flow after running:

```
<object-to-byte-array-transformer/>
```

the S3 payload is gone, so `#[payload.getKey()]` will fail in the next processor:

```
  <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\output" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="#[payload.getKey()] "></file:outbound-endpoint>
```

I've run this without problems:

```
<flow name="listobjects">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8083" path="listobjects" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <s3:list-objects config-ref="Amazon_S3" bucketName="mule_test"  doc:name="Amazon S3" maxKeys="5" />
    <foreach collection="#[payload]" doc:name="For Each">
     <logger message=" inside foreach...... #[payload.getKey()]  ...." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <set-variable variableName="fileKey" value="#[payload.getKey()]" doc:name="Variable" />
        <s3:get-object-content config-ref="Amazon_S3" bucketName="#[payload.getBucketName()]" key="#[payload.getKey()]"  doc:name="Amazon S3"/>
        <object-to-byte-array-transformer/>
      <file:outbound-endpoint path="/tmp" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="#[flowVars.fileKey] "></file:outbound-endpoint> 
    </foreach>
    <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Content-Type" />
    <set-payload value="{'result': 'ok'}"/>
</flow>
```